# Calculate residues in all singularities

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I need to calculate residues in all singularities of $f(z) = e^{z^2 + \frac{1}{z^2}}$. I found that point $z_0 = 0$ is a pole, but i can`t find an order of it. I tried to calculate the derivatives of $\frac{1}{e^{z^2 + \frac{1}{z^2}}}$ to find the order of derivative, limit of which as n approaches $0$ doesnt equal zero or $inf$, but failed. Am i doing something wrong? Please help.

Comment: for every $z$ : $e^{z^2} = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2m}}{m!}$ and for $|z| > 0$ : $e^{z^{-2}} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-2k}}{k!}$ so that for $|z| > 0$ : $\displaystyle e^{z^2+z^{-2}} =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{-2k}}{k!}  \sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2m}}{m!} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty z^{2n} \sum_{m-k = n, k \ge 0, m \ge 0} \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{m!} =  \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty z^{2n}  \sum_{k = \max(n,0)}^\infty  \frac{1}{k!}\frac{1}{(k-n)!}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At $z=0$ it is not a pole, it is an essential singularity. It's easy to see this if you look at the Laurent series representation:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z^2 + 1/z^2)^n}{n!} \quad (|z| > 0)$$

In particular, you can see that there won't be a largest negative power of $z$ in this expansion since each $n$th term contributes a $z^{-2n}$ term.

Hence, the residue is the coefficient of the $\frac{1}{z}$ term in this series. Each term in the series only contributes even powers of $z$, hence the coefficient is zero.

Comment: Thank you. I coudn`t see that limit doesnt exist for some reason :/